# Looping in PowerShell with API

Tags: powershell, loops

Trying to build a loop for a response I get digging through an API call. The purpose is to take the last `identification` value and if the value is not `$null`, then return results of identification into a variable. I know my `$xml` variable will have be put into the loop as it is determining whether or not there is an identification property to compare against.

```
$homeUri = "https://example.com" 
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $homeUri  
$output = $output.identification 

$xml = [xml]@"   <xml>
    <sort>
      <Parameters="identification" operator="GREATER">$($output.identification)</Parameters>
    </sort>   </xml> "@

$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $homeUri -Body $xml
```

I am struggling to understand how to implement `$xml` into the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here? Loop what?

What would you expect as a result?